# Join tables insert into third

Tags: postgresql

**Table1**

```
id  class_id  class
1   
2   
3
```

**Table2**

```
sameid  class_id
2       20
3       30
1       40
```

**Table3**

```
class_id    desc
30          forest
40          urban
20          water
```

I want to insert Table3.class_id and Table3.desc into Table1.class_id and Table1.class by joining Table1-Table2-Table3.

**So I try:**

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (class_id,class)
SELECT Table3.class_id, Table3.desc
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.class_id=Table3.class_id
WHERE Table1.id = Table2.sameid
```

But I get error: invalid reference FROM-clause entry for table "Table1". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it's appropriate would you consider just making Table1 a view instead?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa I want it as a table. I dont know if i could make a view and then save as a table? I have many tables like 2,3 above which I want to add values from to a Table1 of many columns. I have no idea what the best workflow is, im a noob. I Think ill try many CTE like in the answer.

Comment: No problem, if you're quite new then do what works for you. However do try to learn some good techniques along the way. It sounds like views could be what you need, once you've created a view you can select from it just like you would a table. You never need to run your insert script again, the view is always up to date as it runs the query you've specified.

Comment: I agree with Alexander. A view is most probably the better solution. I would only consider a table like that if some really pressing performance problems would force me to. And then I'd probably use a materialized view instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do an update join with the help of the following CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t2.sameid, t2.class_id, t3.desc
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN table3 t3
        ON t2.class_id = t3.class_id
)

UPDATE table1 AS t1
SET
    class_id = t2.class_id,
    class    = t2.desc
FROM cte AS t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.sameid;
```

The strategy here is to create a CTE which contains all the columns we want to use in the update, addressable by `sameid`, which maps to the `id` in `table1`.  Then, we just use a Postgres update join to bring in the values.

Comment: It doesn't.  I had a typo, sorry.

Comment: Will cte remain in memory for as long as the query is executed? For example can I use the same cte again for another update further down in the query without having to recreate it?

Comment: @BERA I'm not an expert in Postgres.  AFAIK the CTE will be materialized when you run it, but you may refer to it multiple times in a query which follows its definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware an accepted answer already exists, but you can leverage **views** if you want to keep your "Table1" concept up to date without having to periodically insert more data

```
CREATE VIEW Table1_vw AS
SELECT Table3.class_id, Table3.desc
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.class_id=Table3.class_id
WHERE Table1.id = Table2.sameid
```

Then you can query `Table1_vw` as if it was a real table

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_vw;
```

**Edit:** Read through the comments to see how inserts and updates work in the context of views.

Comment: You _can_ make such a view updatable

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name interesting, I didn't know that - just had a quick Google, would I be right in saying you can update the fields with cascaded? However inserting new data still seems out of the question.

Comment: An `instead of` trigger can support insert, delete and update statements: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html#SUPPORTED-TRIGGER-TYPES The `cascaded` option only works for [automatically updateable views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS) which a view with a join is not